# iOS camera issue (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera

I am trying to run a conditional to test whether an the image is "silhouette.png" before it overwrites the image with the picture taken from a camera using the imagePickerController.

The conditional isn't working and causing my app to crash, because imageView1.image is "Optional( size {225, 225} orientation 0 scale 1.000000)" and keeps changing, based of my println() value.  How do I go about checking to see if imageView1.image is silhouette.png(default image placeholder) and not a new image from the camera (newMedia == true)?

I am doing this conditional because I want there are multiple imageViews on my viewController, and I want the imagePickerController to check the images before overwriting them.

Thank you.

```
func imagePickerController(picker:UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject:AnyObject]){
    //what happens after the picture is chosen
    let oldImage = UIImage(named:"silhouette.png")
    println(imageView1.image)
    //if conditional that isn't working
    if imageView1.image == oldImage {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if mediaType.isEqualToString(kUTTypeImage as NSString as String){
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView1.image = image
        if (newMedia == true){
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditionnal can't work, you are comparing two different instance of the same Image. It will never work.

An other solution would be to compare both image data like this:

```
    let data1 =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(oldImage)
    let data2 =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView1.image)

    if data2.isEqualToData(data1) {
        //Do your stuff
    }
```